# Inicializar, armar y leer Arrays

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un reporte donde se hace necesario sumar valores del dia y meses del año y totalizar por almacen, cliente, producto y total general, entonces debo crear variables asi:

```
$totalDia1Cliente += $row['subtotal'];
$totalDia1Cliente += $row['Descuento'];
$totalDia1Cliente += $row['impuesto']; 
$totalDia1Cliente += $row['total'];
// asi hasta el Dia31 para el almacen, los productos y el total general

$totalMes1Cliente += $row['subtotal'];
$totalMes1Cliente += $row['Descuento'];
$totalMes1Cliente += $row['impuesto']; 
$totalMes1Cliente += $row['total'];
// hasta el mes 12 para el almacen, los clientes, los productos y el total general
```

al totalizar cada uno de las agrupaciones de debe de inicializar (igualar a cero) cada una de las variables correspondiente, en fin hay que manejar mas de 1000 variables he intentado hacerlo con arrays pero no me ha funcionado. Agradezco la orintacion para inicializar, armar y leer los array.

Comment: Como intentaste hacerlo con arrays?

Comment: uno de los array lo inicio ´$totalsProduct=[];´ luego le ingreso un valor         ´$totalsProduct['idt_quantity'] += $row['idt_quantity']; ´ pero da error la primera vez entonces lo valido        

´ if (!isset($totalsProduct['idt_quantity'])){
            $totalsProduct['idt_quantity'] = 0;
        }¨

pero es hasta mas complicado hacerlo para todas las variables